# Can't find matching rows in table error when trying to grant privileges to mariadb user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

It seems like this should be easy...I literally pulled this command from the mysql handbook, changed the privileges granted *slightly* and the user. I'm just trying to add privileges to a user and I'm getting an error in the command line. Here is the command I'm trying to send through:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON mytable.* TO 'myclient';
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR 1133 (28000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

The table and the user already exist. Here is the part of the mysql handbook I'm referencing:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html

What am I doing wrong here?

(MariaDB version 10.1.34 on Ubuntu server 18.04)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user`. You might also want to use `SHOW GRANTS` to see if you find the user you want to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privilege-system.html)

> As a user, when you connect to a MySQL server, your identity is
>   determined by the host from which you connect and the user name you
>   specify.

So, MySQL privileges are not granted to the named user, but to a user connecting from a particular host. This way the named user can have different privileges depending on where they connect from.

When granting privileges it's usual to specify both the `user` and `host` parts so that they can be matched to the correct user and host combination. If the host part is omitted, as here, then MySQL assumes that the host is the wildcard '%' (i.e. from anywhere). Your command is therefore treated as

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON mytable.* TO 'myclient'@'%';
```

and the error message you quote means that there is no record in the mysql.user table where `user` = 'myclient' and `host` = '%'.